Jhipster microservice application failed to determine a suitable driver class
I have generated a microservice application with Jhipster microservice, configured db url on dev. But I start the application it throws this error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles dev,@spring.profiles.active@ are currently active).
 


This is the yaml config in my app-dev.yaml:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mservicedb
    username: postgres
    password: mysecretpassword
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
  elasticsearch:
    uris: http://localhost:9200
  liquibase:
    # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
    contexts: dev, faker
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mservicedb
  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S # 1 second, see the ISO 8601 standard
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false

Expecting the application to be up and running. because it works well when I generate a monolithic application
Below is my jhipster info
<summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary>
<pre>
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "baseName": "gatewayapp",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "cacheProvider": "redis",
    "clientFramework": "no",
    "clientTestFrameworks": null,
    "clientTheme": null,
    "creationTimestamp": 1721566963565,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "entities": [],
    "feignClient": true,
    "jhipsterVersion": "8.6.0",
    "messageBroker": "kafka",
    "microfrontend": null,
    "microfrontends": [],
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "packageName": "company.avalonapp.api",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "reactive": false,
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "serverPort": 8081,
    "serverSideOptions": [
      "searchEngine:elasticsearch",
      "messageBroker:kafka"
    ],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "syncUserWithIdp": true,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": null
  }
}
</pre>
</details>


##### **Environment and Tools**

java version "22.0.1" 2024-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)

git version 2.45.2.windows.1

node: v20.15.1
npm: 10.7.0

Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b


Thanks

I think default profile dev is not getting loaded
check the loaded profile under banner Startup profile(s) @spring.profiles.active@
it should be Startup profile(s) dev ::
use the command
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
if you are using intelij run/debug configuration then set environment variable as spring.profiles.active=dev
